# windows 8 PATH causes problems

Tags: python, c++, mingw, atom-editor

I have been trying to use both C++ and python on the atom editor, so I needed to add two paths to my system (The python3 executable and the MinGW compiler executable). The problem is apparently I cannot add two different paths to my system, so I have to change paths and restart atom each time I need to change languages.

In addition, this causes lots of problems, for example, I can't use pip anymore (the command tells me there is no such thing as pip!) even though it used to work perfectly before.

Just please tell me how can I fix the pip problem, I've used it before to install pytz, but after changing paths from Python to MinGW and back again to Python it stopped working.

I have a windows 8 32-bit system

Comment: You can just have multiple folders on your path. Separate them with a semi-colon, i.e. `C:\some\path;C:\some\other\path`.

Comment: Note that when you try making PATH over 2047 characters long then it likely gets corrupted.